# Custom Toolbar in Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I have used [Google's solution for multiple back stacks](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) in Navigation Component. I want to setup a custom AppBar at the activity level(Idea is to have a Toolbar, A FragmentContainerView, and BottomNavigationView)

This works fine except this sets the title of the Toolbar automatically (doesn't call any particular method in the file I have linked as far as I know) .

I want to build a custom toolbar which has a TextView with multiple colors(As in half of the title is black , other half is yellow).

Any solution how to build a custom toolbar in this solution would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can read this document about handle navigation component back stack with appBar configuration
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

and also you can watch this course for make custom toolbar
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=e5_C9e_gKOM

Comment: This will not work since it can only define the AppBar titles . I want to build a fully custom solution